# Website's Dropdown doesn't appear in flutter webiew

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

[I am trying to use flutter webview for my website the issue I am facing is the Dropdown menu appear in the windows browser but not in flutter webview. Is there any possible way to use webview which can also show the drop-down? Website is responsive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7TV8.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

make sure to enable the javascript

```
WebView(
        initialUrl: ur,
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,)
```